# How to change display resolution for Armbian ?

Tags: resolution, armbian

I have a BananaPI M1 and I have installed the Armbian. The current resolution is 1920 x 1080 (px) which is very small. There is only 1920x1080 option in Settings> Display.
How can I shrink this?

**Version:**

Armbian 5.35 Bananapi

Ubuntu xenial default 3.4.113

Comment: this completely unrelated, but how much big is your monitor? because 1920x1080 is ok with at least 24' monitors!

Answer (score 2):

First you must use this command to calculate the parameters you need to insert into `xrandr`:

```
cvt 1366 768
```

You can change `1366 768` as based on your desire mostly, use your favorite resolution. the above command will give you output something like this:

```
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

Copy the string after `Modeline`:

```
"1368x768_60.00" 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

then insert it into the below command:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00" 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

I think you using VGA monitor, so this command will assign this resolution to your monitors settings:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1368x768_60.00"
```

Finally you can active it with this command:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1368x768_60.00"
```

**Please remember THE VGA1 is completely based on your device! if you are using something else than VGA, replace this parameter with another value.**